# Real Time Audio Visualizer

Tags: itunes, video, music

I'm wondering if this software exists for Mac.  Where it will use whatever sound is currently being outputted and visualize it.  I would even take using the microphone to receive the sound.

Is there stand alone software that can do this?  Or a way to route the current audio into iTunes or Winamp and use their visualizer?

Comment: The use whatever sounds is bit brought term?

Comment: What do you mean by "visualize it"? Do you now what kind of visualization you're after? Peak power? Average power? Time-based spectrograph? Something else?

Comment: @Buscar웃 Anything coming out of my computer's speakers.

Comment: @IanC. Really any sort of graphic representation that would be entertaining to watch.

Comment: OK, lets see what we can do for you than. But need you to provide your hardware details including you graphics card.

Comment: Any budget constrains ?